# Incorrect typing/declaration for Cypress custom mount command

Tags: jquery, typescript, cypress

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/24479

Awhile back, this PR was merged and closed with the intention of better typing the response from Cypress' mount function, which as of version 11, returns a wrapper (vue instance) and component that can be deconstructed alongside a `JQuery<HTMLElement>`. However, with my current typescript config, this is resulting in build errors. I've been working on this for days and I cannot figure out why either props or `component, wrapper` is throwing an error when my tests pass repeatedly. Props passes props to the mounted component and the response returns a component and wrapper instance.

Here's a repo to reproduce within VSCode after `npm install` and `npm run build`: https://github.com/Johnsoct/ts-cy

[image]

[image]

```
// TSConfig
// TSConfig
// TSConfig
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Base Options: */
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "paths": {
      "@cypress/*": [
        "cypress/*"
      ],
      "@src/*": [
        "src/*"
      ],
      "@ts/*": [
        "types/*"
      ],
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "types": [
      "cypress",
      "jsdom",
      "node",
    ],
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,

    /* Strictness */
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "strict": true,

    /* If transpiling with TypeScript: */
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "module": "es2022",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,

    /* AND if you're building for a library: */
    "declaration": true,

    /* AND if you're building for a library in a monorepo: */
    "composite": false, // Throws reference errors in VSCode if true
    "declarationMap": true,

    /* If your code runs in the DOM: */
    "lib": [
      "es2022",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable"
    ],
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "cypress.d.ts",
    "env.d.ts",
    "cypress.config.ts",
    "eslint.config.js",
    "vite.config.ts",
    "vitest.config.ts",
    "cypress/**/*",
    "src/**/*",
    "types/**/*",
  ]
}

// cypress.d.ts
// cypress.d.ts
// cypress.d.ts
import { mount } from 'cypress/vue';

type MountParams = Parameters<typeof mount>
type OptionsParam = MountParams[1]

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      // mount: typeof mount,
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
      mount(component: any, options?: OptionsParam): Chainable<any>
    }
  }
}

// base-input.cy.ts (one test example)
// base-input.cy.ts (one test example)
// base-input.cy.ts (one test example)
it.only('@input emits "" from user input when currency prop is true and user input is "invalid"', () => {
      const expectedOutput = '';
      const inputText = 'ff';

      cy.mount(BaseInput, {
        props: {
          currency: true,
        },
      });

      cy
        .get(BASE_INPUT.inputs.input)
        .type(inputText);

      cy
        .get('@vue')
        .should(({ component, wrapper }) => {
          console.log(wrapper);
          wrapper
            .emitted('input')
            .forEach((arrayOfSingleEmit) => {
              const inputEvent = arrayOfSingleEmit[0];
              expect(inputEvent).to.equal(expectedOutput);
            });
        });

      cy
        .get(BASE_INPUT.inputs.input)
        .should('have.value', inputText);
    });
```

Comment: I made a repo for this. `npm install` then `npm run test:unit:dev` to see the test passing. https://github.com/Johnsoct/ts-cy